# HandBreak installtion fail

Tags: package-management, ppa, handbrake

I just got Ubuntu the other day on my brand spanking new, yummy 8-core PC.
Anyways, i was trying to get Handbrake to convert/compress my videos for file transfer.
So I looked it up, and found the "ppa" installation that went something like;

```
# To add one of these to your sources, simply run:    
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots depending on which you want. 
# To install HandBrake, run:
sudo apt-get update  sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk


# Alternatively, if you would prefer the CLI over the GUI, replace the last line with:  
sudo apt-get install handbrake-client
```

Anyway, I did this, but when I did `sudo apt-get install handbreak-gtk` it came up with:

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake-client.
Reading package lists... Done.
Building dependency tree.
Reading state information... Done.

E: Unable to locate package handbrake-client
```

Any help?

Comment: You did `sudo apt-get install handbreak-gtk` but the output you paste is `sudo apt-get install handbrake-client.` Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases shows there's some omitted portions of the required addition. It's gotta start with http://ppa.launchpad.net/ and there are different lines for different Ubuntu versions... and none yet for 13.10.

Comment: Damn, that sucks. Im on 13.10 so, thanks anyway :D